# PHP submit button in echo that can do a little javascripting

Tags: javascript, php, html, button

I currently have a script that outputs certain values in a db and it's working as intended. But now, I am trying to add a column with buttons. Very every row that the db spits out, I need a button that would open run a javascript function and then open a window. This works in HTML just fine, but because its in PHP and in #echo its not working. It has to do something with my quotes, but I can't seem to figure it out. Does someone know how to have a button embedded in an echo that can also do javascript?
FYI - I would like the buttons to be within the echo so if there are 10 rows, 10 buttons will show up. Thanks!

```
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs)) 
{

echo '
    <tr>
    <td class="td" valign="top">
    <input type="submit" name="SendEmailManually" value="Submit" onclick="window.open("index.php","newWin", "width=400,height=400")" /></td>
    <td class="td" valign="top">' . $Value1 . '</td>
    <td class="td" valign="top">' . $Value2 . '</td>
            <td class="td" valign="top">' . $Value3 . '</td>
            <td class="td" valign="top">' . $Value4 . '</td>
    </tr> 
';
}
```

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like?

Comment: Your `onclick` attribute can't have double quotes within double quotes.

Comment: You could avoid this by not using inline javascript

Comment: @SSHThis - the table currently goes like this - |button|$Value1|$Value2|$Value3|$Value4 - The button shows but does nothing when I click it.

Comment: @RUJordan - I did have a function but it still did not work. I then tried the inline javascript in hoping that would work.

Comment: @RUJordan - Ugh, ITS WORKING NOW!

Comment: @RUJordan - I went ahead and put the function back in and played with the quotes like you recommended. It works like a charm!

Comment: @Yusof I didn't recommend that, I recommended an exterior script to avoid the quote issue entirely

Comment: @RUJordan - I will try the querySelector() now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't use inline javascript, it's ugly and even worse so when you need to escape quotes to make it work.

```
function openIndex() {
    window.open("index.php","newWin", "width=400,height=400");
}
```

throw your window code into a function, and assign the input an id (remove the onclick attribute).

Or, if no id is to be assigned, use `querySelector()`.

```
var x = document.querySelector("[name='SendEmailManually']");
x.addEventListener("click",openIndex,false);
```

Add your event listener, and suddenly you have some good looking code that works nicely with delegated events.

Answer (score 0):

You are using double quotes, which interfere with the double quotes encasing the value of the `onclick` attribute. Use single quotes instead. `"window.open('index.php','newWin', 'width=400,height=400')"`